# What happens at low level when I add a column to a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table with number of rows in the order of billions. Let's say I want to add a column to that table. I would like to know what happens behind the scene to know the cost, expected time of this query.

Doesn't relational databases store row data pointers together so it will have to lookup each row to add a pointer of the added column to the end of that row block on disk? This is my current understanding.

Comment: Please tag only one RDBMS for a broad question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres nothing really happens.

It just adds a row to the system catalogs so that it knows that you added a column. It doesn't even touch the table data. So even on a table with a billion rows this would only take a few milliseconds once it could obtain the exclusive lock on the table.

Starting with Postgres 11, this even is the case when adding a NOT NULL column with a constant as the default value, e.g. `add some_flag integer not null default 42`

If the default value is a volatile function (e.g. `current_timestamp`), Postgres is forced to call this once for each row and put in the result of that. Then this would take a substantial amount of time to add the column with billions of rows.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL i found this article from may 2018: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-innodb-now-supports-instant-add-column/

> **MySQL 8.0: InnoDB now supports Instant ADD COLUMN**
>
> Dictionary, InnoDB, MySQLDDL operationBin Su Instant DDL has been
> one of the most requested InnoDB features for a very long time. With
> ever larger and rapidly growing datasets the ability to do DDL
> instantly is a must have feature in any web scale database.
> Developers constantly need to add new columns to meet the constantly
> changing business requirements.  The ability to add ADD COLUMNs
> instantly is the first in a series of DDL statements that we plan to
> do instantly. The move to  a new transactional data dictionary in
> MySQL 8.0 has made this task a lot easier for us.  Prior to MySQL 8.0
> the meta-data (data dictionary) was stored in flat files called .frm
> files. The .frm files are in  an arcane format that is long past its
> use by date.

After this, the article has some more details about how it used to be (in 5.6), and how it's done.